# Библиотека datetime не часы и минуты, а полностью все переменные

Tags: python, datetime

Нужно получить часы и минуты, но код выдает все значения (`гггг-мм-дд чч:мм:сс`).

Вот код:

```
import datetime as dt
DATABASE = {
'Серёга': 'Омск',
'Соня': 'Москва',
'Дима': 'Челябинск',
'Алина': 'Красноярск',
'Егор': 'Пермь'
}
UTC_OFFSET = {
'Санкт-Петербург': 3,
'Москва': 3,
'Самара': 4,
'Новосибирск': 7,
'Екатеринбург': 5,
'Нижний Новгород': 3,
'Казань': 3,
'Челябинск': 5,
'Омск': 6,
'Ростов-на-Дону': 3,
'Уфа': 5,
'Красноярск': 7,
'Пермь': 5,
'Воронеж': 3,
'Волгоград': 4,
'Краснодар': 3,
'Калининград': 2
}
def what_time(friend):
    utc_time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    city = DATABASE[friend]
    a=UTC_OFFSET[city]
    san=utc_time + dt.timedelta(hours=a)
    san.strftime('%H %M')
    return san
print(what_time('Соня'))
```

Comment: Как вариант можно так: dt.datetime.utcnow().time() Выдаст вам три значения. Берете первых два, это будут часы и минуты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно объединить

```
san.strftime('%H %M')
return san
```

в

```
 return san.strftime('%H %M')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо команды

```
san.strftime('%H %M')
```

которая, хотя и *конвертирует* значение переменой `san` в строку часов и минут, но эту строку **нигде не сохраняет** (т.е. результат просто отбросит, не используя его),

примените

```
san = san.strftime('%H:%M')          # я добавил двоеточие между часами и минутами
```

чем полученную строку сохраните обратно в переменную `san`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция what_time возвращает объект datetime, а не строку. Вы вызываете strftime для форматирования времени, но не используете результат этого вызова. Вам нужно присвоить результат strftime переменной и вернуть эту переменную

```
def what_time(friend):
    utc_time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    city = DATABASE[friend]
    a=UTC_OFFSET[city]
    san=utc_time + dt.timedelta(hours=a)
    formatted_time = san.strftime('%H:%M')  # Используйте результат strftime
    return formatted_time  # Возвращайте отформатированное время
print(what_time('Соня'))
```